Linux-base system. Is user run application with user permissions or Application runs with context of user permissions?
We have an Ubuntu server, where we run Java spring application under specificuser user. Java app has multiple threads, and so on. Inside threads, it is going to a folder
/mnt/somefolder/somechildfolder
somechildfolder -> has permissions drwxrwx--- specificuser specificgroup. ( so user specificuser can read, write execute folder, but ALL users can't read, write,execute)
Inside this somechildfolder we have images. With permissions
-rwxrwx--- specificuser specificgroup SOMEIMAGE ( so user specificuser can read, write,execute image, but not ALL users can read, write, execute)
java app run a command exiftool -someField=someValue SOMEIMAGE
Logs of java app, which run exiftool says that it can't update SOMEIMAGE because it doesn't have permissions.
When I login to the system as specificuser -> go to folder /mnt/somefolder/somechildfolder -> run command exiftool -someField=someValue SOMEIMAGE => it is working, and image was updated.
My understanding of the issue is that:

when you run command exiftool under user specificuser inside a terminal it takes permission of the user, which is rwx so it can update.
when java app run as user specificuser -> the SYSTEM creates multiple threads, that are working in parallel, and it tries to execute the code inside somechildfolder, and since it has permissions --- for a folder, the java app can't initialize and run the command exiftool

So the question is: does user specificuser run the java app with his permissions, or some child processes of java app can run itself WITH CONTEXT OF A USER specificuser permissions ?

Unless a program has the setuid flag set in its permission modes, it runs with the permissions of whoever runs it. If it has the setuid flag, it runs with the permissions of the owner of the program.

Hello, thanks for your reply, what about the situation when we login to ubuntu with "somedev" user, we run java app with systemctl, which specified in config "specificuser" user, it went to mount folder, where specificuser  has permission drwxrwx---, and them java app run exiftool that installed on this Ubuntu ?

It runs as "specificuser", since systemd uses the user specific in the service config file. The mount point is irrelevant.

Unless exiftool is setuid, it runs with the permissions of the user who runs it.
